# Array Filter return all when empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm filtering an ng-repeat with an array. I would like the ng-repeat to show everything when the filterarray is empty.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='Test'>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='letter in letters | inArray:filterBy:"id"'>{{letter.id}}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module('Test', [])
.filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
            });
        }

    };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.letters = [
    {id: 'a', name:'nameA'},
    {id: 'b', name:'nameB'},
    {id: 'c', name:'nameC'},
    {id: 'd', name:'nameD'},
    {id: 'e', name:'nameE'}
  ];

  $scope.filterBy = [];
}
```

JSBIN:
http://jsbin.com/buteyorabi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the length of your `arrayFilter`. If length = 0 return your `list`;

```
    if(arrayFilter && arrayFilter.length > 0){
        return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
            return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
        });
    }

    return list;
```

Full Example: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/covebequhu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

The return array should be something like this:

```
.filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                var result = arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]);
                return (result != -1)?listItem:/*something to like to return*/;
            });
        }

    };
});
```